# python multiplication tables with while loops with different starting int

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

i need help with some homework. they want me to make a 10x10 multiplication tables using multiple while loops and nesting. they want the user to be prompted for the first number for the row and column. so if the you give 3 for column and 12 for the row it would look like this:

```
       3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12
   --------------------------------------------------
12|   36   48   60   72   84   96  108  120  132  144
13|   39   52   65   78   91  104  117  130  143  156
14|   42   56   70   84   98  112  126  140  154  168
15|   45   60   75   90  105  120  135  150  165  180
16|   48   64   80   96  112  128  144  160  176  192
17|   51   68   85  102  119  136  153  170  187  204
18|   54   72   90  108  126  144  162  180  198  216
19|   57   76   95  114  133  152  171  190  209  228
20|   60   80  100  120  140  160  180  200  220  240
21|   63   84  105  126  147  168  189  210  231  252
```

this is what i found with the internet search help:

```
row = int(input("Enter the first row number: " ))
while(row <= 10):
    column = int(input("Enter the frist column number: "))
    while(column <= 10):
        if(row+column==0):
            print('{:4s}'.format(''),end = '') #corner
        elif(row*column==0):
            print('{:4d}'.format(row+column),end = '') # border
        else:
            print('{:4d}'.format(row*column),end = '') # table
        column=column+1   
    print()
    row=row+1
```

if anyone could help me i would be very thankful

Comment: `row = int(input("Enter the first row number: " ))
while(row <= 10):
    column = int(input("Enter the frist column number: "))
    while(column <= 10):
        if(row+column==0):
            print('{:4s}'.format(''),end = '') #corner
        elif(row*column==0):`
            `print('{:4d}'.format(row+column),end = '') # border
        else:
            print('{:4d}'.format(row*column),end = '') # table
        column=column+1   
   print()
    row=row+1

Answer (score 0):

It should look something more like this:

```
row1 = int(input("Enter the first row number: " ))
column1 = int(input("Enter the first column number: "))

# TODO: print header

for row in range(row1, row1 + 10):
    for column in range(column1, column1 + 10):
        # TODO
```

That is, you only prompt for input twice, not (1+N) times, and you use the built-in function `range()` to generate the lists of rows and columns to iterate over.